# Configure prerender io angular app working on apache

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, prerender

After a lot of time lost trying to make my site SEO friendly without rendering it, it seems that is imposible with AngularJS. Now I'm trying to do it with prerender io but i dont quite get the configuration. I signed up on prerender io and i got my token i made my htacess file but i still get the message **You need to install your Prerender token before you can start caching your pages.**

my htacess file is made from recomendation on official preredner io github

**htacess**

```
  RewriteEngine On
# If requested resource exists as a file or directory
  # (REQUEST_FILENAME is only relative in virtualhost context, so not usable)
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    # Go to it as is
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If non existent
    # If path ends with / and is not just a single /, redirect to without the trailing /
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/$
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
      RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R,QSA,L]      

  # Handle Prerender.io
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "mytoken"

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

    # Proxy the request
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://service.prerender.io/http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [P,L]

  # If non existent
    # Accept everything on index.html
    RewriteRule ^ /index.html#!
```

I'm working in html5 mode, but have hashbang fallback and it works just fine.

**MAIN.JS**

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routes, $location) {
    $location.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    $routes

**HTML**

```
<head >
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/">
   <meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

Comment: Did you finally solved this? I got the same issue..

Comment: Sorry I'm late with answer yes i did find solution i made everything from start, entered my token and it worked. Todd Hopper from PrerenderIO was very helpful with it you should contact him if it still doesn't work for you

Comment: What do you mean by "you need to install the token"? Im having the same problem too, and i have my token in my .htaccess, still doesnt seem to be working. Thanks

Comment: you should contact Todd Hopper show him the code then. This was the problem for me i re-entered the token. Nothing more.